# Getting MathView to work in Android

Tags: android

Does anyone have any experience using MathView in Android Studio? I downloaded the MathView-0.0.6.aar file, and added followed the instructions on github to add it as a dependency. But when I try to put in a Mathview in one of my XML files, I get this error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.github.kexanie.library.MathView.getSettings()Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;   at io.github.kexanie.library.MathView.<init>(MathView.java:24)`

Comment: try this dependencies ,dependencies {
    compile 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
}

Comment: I have that line in my build.gradle file, but still get the error :( The error, by the way, shows up in the preview window with the heading "Rendering Problems"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
compile 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
```

and in your xml file add this:

```
<io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
    android:id="@+id/math_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:engine="MathJax" />
```