# Android - How to make MathView work on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, mathjax

I'm interested in math formulas and searching I stumbled with this [MathView](https://github.com/kexanie/MathView), it fills my needs of my app... but I cannot make it work, I did follow the steps to import via Maven repository the dependencies, and I'm having the same problem as here [Getting MathView to work in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970903/getting-mathview-to-work-in-android)

Tools:

- **Android Studio 2.2**
- Windows 10 Pro x64
- Gradle dependencies:

  ```
      dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
          exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
      })
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
      compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
      compile 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }
  ```

Here is my layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <io.github.kexanie.library.MathView
        android:id="@+id/formula_test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        auto:text="When \\(a \\ne 0\\), there are two solutions to \\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\\)
        and they are $$x = {-b \\pm \\sqrt{b^2-4ac} \\over 2a}.$$"
        auto:engine="MathJax">

    </io.github.kexanie.library.MathView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the complete error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.github.kexanie.library.MathView.getSettings()Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;
    at io.github.kexanie.library.MathView.<init>(MathView.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor482.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:105)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:186)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:334)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:345)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:245)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$72(RenderTask.java:659)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

I'm also aware of MathJax and KaTeX but I couldn't find any relevant info on how to integrate in Android

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You import the module of in mathview.
Open file->new module->gradle, here you want to import the mathview from github folder.

Then open project file project sturture=>App>dependencies>"+">mathview>ok

Then in project gradle

```
classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.2'
classpath "com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.3"
```