Using MathView library
Writing a Java program that contains mathexpressions. Following link contains a MathView:
MathView-Github-link
Is it possible to download the code and make it a library and then attach it to a Android Studio project?
I tried to add the dependency to the build.gradle as stated in the link:
`compile 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'`

get the following error:
Could not find io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6

Did you also add the jcenter repository as the documentation says? Can you [edit] your question and share the build script as a [mcve]? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732578/android-how-to-make-mathview-work-on-android

Please make sure your project level build.gradle includes the mavenCentral repository:
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
}

Then add the dependency in your app level build.gradle with implementation (not with compile)
implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'


I added the above code in the 2 build.gradle as stated. get the following error: "Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'"

Add the repositories block in the settings.gradle.kts file and not the build.gradle.kts files

removed repo block from build.gradle. the 2 repos were already included in the settings.gradle.  Now, following error: Could not find io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6.

Have you tried the 0.0.5 version?

yes. I tried it now. same error. is it possible to download the code and somehow make a library and then import the library into the project?

Yes, you can add it. They have obvious instructions for it on the official repository
